# libcairo-2.dll missing at runtime on MSYS2

Tags: c, cairo, msys2

Here's simple test to get started writing code that uses Cairo on MSYS2:

```
#include <cairo.h>

int main() {
  cairo_surface_t *surface = cairo_image_surface_create(CAIRO_FORMAT_ARGB32, 300, 300);
  cairo_t *cr = cairo_create(surface);

  cairo_set_line_width(cr, 10.0);
  cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 0, 0, 0);
  cairo_move_to(cr, 10.0, 10.0);
  cairo_line_to(cr, 100.0, 100.0);
  cairo_stroke(cr);

  cairo_destroy(cr);
  cairo_surface_write_to_png(surface, "c.png");
  cairo_surface_destroy(surface);

  return 0;
}
```

This code builds and executes properly on Darwin/MacPorts with this command:

```
$ gcc c.c -o c `pkg-config cairo --libs --cflags`
```

Under Win8/MSYS2, I have installed the `mingw-w64-x86_64-cairo` package. The same `gcc` build command succeeds, but running the resulting executable results in this error:

```
C:/msys64/path/to/c.exe: error while loading shared libraries: libcairo-2.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have tried to find `libcairo-2.dll` inside of MSYS2, but I don't see anything. A Google search doesn't get me any closer.

I suspect that this is part of the learning curve of MSYS2 development; what am I missing?

Comment: Why the `-lcairo`? pkg-config gives you that already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have `/mingw64/bin` in your `PATH` environment variable when running the compiled executable?

`libcairo-2.dll` (and lots of other .dll files) lives in `/mingw64/bin`.

This is already solved in the MinGW shell, which is *not the same* as the MSYS2 shell. Both are there in the start menu.

Comment: I should've been more explicit: when you tried to run your dynamically linked cairo sample, did your PATH environment variable include /mingw64/bin?

Comment: As in:

PATH=/mingw64/bin:$PATH ./c.exe

Comment: Yes, I figured that out from your answer content. That is exactly what I was missing. Thanks, Ray.

Comment: Your other option is to stick to using mingw64_shell.bat. That way the environment is setup correctly for your needs. Our Wiki on SourceForge is a useful resource. Cheers!

Comment: Ray, I figured that out at the end of the workday yesterday, after banging my head against a separate problem. I've had to revert a couple of things in my .bashrc and now a lot of things make more sense. Thanks for your excellent work.